# std::future or std::shared_future to wait for multiple threads

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a thread that takes each element from a container and sends an upload request to the database. The upload is done synchronously.

The elements in the container are financial contracts and they may or may not have a data structure call ticktable associated to it.

Now, for those contracts which have a ticktable, I have to do a two pass upload.  1) first upload the ticktable to the db. db gives back an id.
2) attach the id to the contract and then upload the contract.

So for example, if I am looping over the container having 100 contracts, lets say 30 of them have ticktable and the rest 70 do not.

I am trying to figure out if `std::future` or a `std::shared_future` is suitable for such a task?

I tried to implement by having a future associated with each of the 30 contracts and call std::async with launch:async policy. So in the first pass of the loop, 3o threads are launched and the returning future is 'moved' to the container associated with the contract.
The other 70 contracts are just uploaded the usual way.

In the second pass, I hope to call `get()` on the stored future. If the request is complete, get the id and complete the contract upload with it. This probably is not going to work because I think moving the future to a container will detach the thread.

Please can you advise what sort of approach should I be taking to implement the behaviour that I want?

Comment: They're done synchronously? You'll know the response when it finishes.

Comment: maybe you could have each worker thread post its results to a thread-safe queue when it completes?

Comment: Why wouldn't a stored procedure insert the tickable and the contract together? What benefit is there to splitting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving a future causes its state to be moved to the target.  So no, you don't have the problem you think you have.

Your ticktable solutions seem like future futures -- one future for the ticktable upload, one for the contract upload.  But a future future is a future in a sense.

So one approach would be to fold the future future into a future.

Suppose you have a contract type `Contract` (which I'll assume is a pseudo-regular type).  Binding your ticktable id is an operation of type `function<void(Contract&)>`.  Amusingly, such an operation can also be a noop.

So have a `std::future<void(Contract&)> Contract::PrepareForUpload() const`.  For each contract you want to upload, go for it.

The ones with a ticktable return a `std::async` generated `future` that owns a thread.

The ones without a ticktable return a deferred `std::async` containing a noop `[]{return [](auto&&...){};}` factory.

Next, add `std::future<void> Contract::Upload(std::function<void(Contract&>) const`, which runs the prep code then does the upload (why do this here? I'll show later).

Now the operation to upload is:

```
auto prep = contract.PrepareForUpload();
auto upload = contract.Upload(prep.get());
```

Now this is a bit annoying.  Doing two things?  Ick.

Why not do it for us?

```
std::future<void> Contract::Upload() const {
  return std::async(
    std::launch::async,
    [this]{
      auto prep = contract.PrepareForUpload();
      return contract.Upload(prep.get());
    }
  );
}
```

and now `Contract::Upload` automatically does the preparation *and* the uploading for you.

This however launches 2 thrads in the ticktable case.  So write a synchronous `PrepareForUpload` that can be called in the "composed" `Upload` case.

If `PrepareForUpload` needs extra arguments, we can pass them to `Upload`.

There are possibly details that you haven't covered that might make this tricker, but the right answer to a chain of futures is usually to collapse the chain into one future.

C++1z has proposals for `.then` and similar functionality in order to make such chain-collapsing easy and efficient.

Comment: Thank you @Yakk. Wow, great to know about being able to fold the future into a future! My requirement was a little simpler though. The contracts upload did not need to be asynchronous. So basically, as I go through the first loop, I keep a vector of future, linked against a contract identifier for all async tick table upload requests that have been posted.  And then in the second pass, I do a get() for all the elements of the vector, get the ticktableid in return and then using the contract id linked with each element, insert the ticktableid to the contract and do a synchronous upload.